# how to save django drag and drop connected list sortable

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

i want to make drag and drop connected list in django. but, how to save sortable2 in models field id_unit?

template html

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

models.py

```
 class Member(models.Model):
    id_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    id_fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_track
```

views.py

```
def fleet_member_add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = FleetMember(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return redirect('fleet_member_add.html', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = FleetMember()
return render(request,'fleet_member_add.html', {'form': form}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Hi @User0511 , did you find the way to save in database? Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI has a widget called a [**sortable**](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) which is just a list of sortable dom elements. It allows you to drag the items around and resort them in a list. Options are passed in an object that you give to the sortable.

Allows the draggable to be dropped onto the specified sortables. If this option is used, a draggable can be dropped onto a sortable list and then becomes part of it.Requires the [jQuery UI Sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin to be included.

**EXAMPLE:**

*Initialize the draggable with the connectToSortable option specified:*

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#my-sortable"
});
```

*Get or set the connectToSortable option, after initialization:*

```
// Getter
var connectToSortable = $( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "connectToSortable" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", "#my-sortable" );
```

jQueryUI also allows you to connect sortables to each other which creates the potential for some interesting user interfaces.

```
$('#my-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '#my-other-list'
});
```

Comment: thanks your explanation, its help me a lot. But how to save in database?